# GWT ScrollHandler

Tags: java, gwt

I have this code

```
@Inject
@DataField("table-col")
SimplePanel tableContainer;

@PostConstruct
public void build() {
    scroll(tableContainer.getElement(), this);
    tableContainer.addHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
            // TODO - Does not trigger
            Window.alert("Scroll");
        }
    }, ScrollEvent.getType());
}
```

My question is why the `tableContainer` Scroll handler does now work when the similar Javascript (JSNI) handler works:

```
public static native void scroll(Element elem, TablePage instance) /*-{
       $wnd.$( elem ).scroll(function() {
            if (elem.scrollTop >= (elem.scrollHeight - elem.offsetHeight)) {                    
                instance.@com.mygwtapp.app.TablePage::scrolledToBottom()();
            }
        });
}-*/;
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The `SimplePanel` doesn't actually listen to `ScrollEvent`, if you want a panel with scroll support you can use `ScrollPanel` (which is a simple panel with scrolling support).

```
ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
scrollPanel.addScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(ScrollEvent scrollEvent) {
        // TODO - Does not trigger
        Window.alert("Scroll");
    }
});
```

In your second way, you're actually adding the event to the element itself, and waiting the event to fired from browser to call your handler. In both ways the event is fired from the browser, but the first one doesn't actually listen to it while the second one listens to it.

Comment: Alternatively, `tableContainer.addDomHandler`, so that the ScrollEvent is actually wired up to the DOM.